# DOJO onclick on a pie chart slice for drill down

Tags: ajax, dojo

I tried to find several places how this work but could not.

The requirement is to drill down by clicking on the slice of the pie to next level. I can get the onclick even but not sure how to get the value from the chart. Everywhere it is pointing to http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/27/dojo-charting-event-support-has-landed/ but nowhere any live demo is given. Till now i have managed to get the onclick.

```
chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales - 2010", chartData);
var h = chart.connectToPlot("default", function(o){ 
if(o.type == "onclick"){
alert("clicked!"); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var store = new dojo.store.Memory({data: [
    { id: '2', value: 10, usedForDrillDown:'x' },
    { id: '3', value: 5, usedForDrillDown: 'y' },
    { id: '4', value: 8, usedForDrillDown:'z' }
]});
// adapter needed, because the chart uses the dojo.data API
var storeAdapter = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({
    objectStore: store
});

var ds = new dojox.charting.DataSeries(
        storeAdapter/*, { query: { needed if the store contains more than data points } }*/);

var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("chart");
chart.addPlot("default", { type: "Pie" });
chart.addSeries("default", ds);

chart.connectToPlot("default", function(evt) {
    if(evt.type == "onclick"){
        var itm = evt.run.source.items[evt.index]; 
        console.dir(itm);
    }     
});

chart.render();
```

Comment: For drill down from pie chart slice I need a id for that slice. So if my chartData is suppose {id1, value1},{id2, value2}..... then i need if I click value1 i should some how get id1.

Comment: I use a data store to provide the chart data. itm is the javascript object from the store and any attributes I need to drill down come from there

Comment: Edited my answer and provided a better example